# TCPDF in codeigniter is not display after upload to apache server

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, tcpdf

I develop my app using CI, and I have a pdf form using TC_PDF. Everything is fine when the app just in localhost. But when I upload to apche server, it gives me blank page. This is my code :

**VIEW**

```
<td  class="center" width="10px">                                                 
   <a class="btn btn-success" >
       <i class="halflings-icon white print" id="print"></i>Print</a>         
</td>

/*for print pdf*/
$(".btn-success").click(function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Cari baris
    var tes = $row.find("#no_request").text(); // Cari Text
    var hapus = tes.substring(10);
    window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url() . 'control_closing/generate_pdf/' ?>" + hapus;
});
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function generate_pdf($idRequest) {
    $data = $this->model_request->selectOneRequest($idRequest); //load model
    foreach ($data as $d) {

        $this->load->library("TC_PDF");
        $pdf = new TC_Pdf(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

        // set document information
        $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
        $pdf->SetAuthor('Dzil');
        $pdf->SetTitle('Form Perbaikan / Permintaan');
        $pdf->SetSubject('TMS/DEPT/IT/06');
        $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, form, perbaikan, Permintaan');
        .......
}
```

**NOTE**
I put tcpdf's folder in application->libraries->tcpdf

**in localhost :** WORKS

```
http://localhost/tresnamuda/control_closing/generate_pdf/002
```

**upload to apache server** . failed

```
http://192.168.5.222/tresnamuda/control_closing/generate_pdf/004
```

Any help it so appreciated.

Comment: how does it fail? have you checked your error logs?

Comment: how to get the error_logs ?

Comment: perhaps see if you can just display the errors instead, by making this your first line of code `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Comment: this is the error : Fatal error: Class 'TC_PDF' not found in /var/www/html/tresnamuda/application/controllers/control_closing.php on line 113

Answer (score 0):

Error "TC_PDF not found" which you are getting is because you haven't uploaded tcpdf library to specific folder on your server. Due to this Class TC_PDF does not exist on server.